# Can I append one value from data to another?

Tags: vue.js

I have got next `data` function:

```
data: function ()  
{
img_starttime: "11:44", // be default it's empty. value only for test
img_startdate: moment(new Date()).add(function () {return this.img_starttime.split(":")[0]}, 'hours')
}
```

I need to increment `img_startdate` to `img_starttime` value. But it's seems that next code do not working, because on console I do not any data increment result.

There is also problem that `img_starttime` is empty, and it's get value only after user will input it, so I can't do any operation like `split` on `undefined` value.

Is there any way to write it's in better way?

Data increment done with moment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the scoping of `this` inside the `moment().add` function.

While you expect your `this.img_starttime` to refer to outside scope, it is actually a new scope created by your `function() {..}` and therefore it is `undefined`

Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40145783/654825

Your code should be as follows:

```js
data: function ()  
{
    img_starttime: "11:44", // be default it's empty. value only for test
    img_startdate: moment(new Date()).add(() => {
        return this.img_starttime.split(":")[0]
    }, 'hours')
}
```

Alternatively, you do not want to use *arrow functions*, you may do the following:

```js
data: function ()  
{
    var self = this;  // 'self' points to 'this' of Vue component
    img_starttime: "11:44", // be default it's empty. value only for test
    img_startdate: moment(new Date()).add(() => {
        return self.img_starttime.split(":")[0]  // 'self' is 'this' of outside scope
    }, 'hours')
}
```

Hope it helps!

**Please note:** I have not used moment.add function and therefore I do not know if that part of code is correct. My answer only points to the scoping error that I noticed.

**Edit: Additional Info**

When I posted the answer, the first thing that grabbed my attention was function scope. On second inspection today, I see few other issues:

- you should be using computed properties for `img_startdate` as it depends on `img_starttime` property. You will not be able to define the dependency in `data` itself.
- your data is a function but it is not returning an object. It should be modified to return an object as shown in the sample code below

changes required:

```js
data: function () {
    return {
        img_starttime: "11:44", // be default it's empty. value only for test
    }
},
computed: {
    img_startdate: function() {
        return moment(new Date()).add(() => {
            return this.img_starttime.split(":")[0]
        }, 'hours')
    }
}
```

Please note: I do not know how `moment.add` works, it is something I never had to use. Currently the code sample above only sets the data and computed properties as per Vue.js expectations, and based on your requirements.

Comment: do you sure that it's possible to do calculation in `data` section? this code do not print `test`:
`img_startdate: moment(new Date()).add(() => {console.log("test"); return this.img_starttime.split(":")[0]}, 'hours'),`

Comment: On second inspection today after your comment, I noticed additional issues. Please check my edits (in second half). Is it possible that you can create a jsFiddle? It will help us understand how you are using this component, and provide better answers.